# Erlang Reader-Writer program

Tags: concurrency, erlang

I'm really new to Erlang and currently I have problems writing a reader-writer program in Erlang. Basically, a shared memory location can be concurrently read by any number of tasks, but when a task must write to the shared memory location, it must have exclusive access. 
My thought would be to spawn reader/write methods to different processes and in those methods just print out something like "Reader reading"/"Writer writing".

However, the usage of semaphore/mutex really bugged me and I have no background in multithreading/concurrency. Can anyone please give some clues how to write such program?

Comment: I think you should ignore the language aspects for now and look into locks, semaphores, mutexes in general to get a feel for multithreading. Then try and implement it in Erlang.

Comment: Erlang doesn't have shared memory except in the form of process tables. Locks, Semaphores, and Mutexes can also be considered somewhat non-idiomatic for erlang since immutable variables and processes sharing data through messages largely makes them unnecessary.

Comment: finalfantasy I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish can you expand a little bit?

Comment: What are you all talking about? Mutexes and Semaphores don't exist in Erlang and are not needed anyway.

Comment: Peer Stritzinger you could in theory write your own in Erlang but there's no need. Thus my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mutexes and Semaphores are just a way of defining synchronization points between two concurrent processes/threads. In erlang these are mostly replaced by sending and receiving messages between erlang processes. An idiomatic way to do this in erlang would be to:

1. spawn a process in erlang that stores your data and listens for messages.
2. spawn other processes that send messages to your storage process asking for data back
   or sending data to be written.

The message box for your data process will ensure that nobody else can write to the data at the same time as everyone else.

Comment: +1. And he could learn about Erlang IN-MEMORY term storage `ETS`

Comment: @MuzaayaJoshua but you still need a wrapper process around the ETS table to control access; otherwise you can easily get a right mess of multiple processes writing to the ETS without any coordination. The you would need a mutex, which is easy to implement in Erlang using a process, but then you might as well have the process directly control the ETS table.

Comment: Why even 'explain' POSIX primitives if your not going to explain that erlang takes care of that by copying all data therefore negating the need for shared memory.